# Spring Boot LDAP Authentication: getting user data at Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have developed a Spring Boot application, and I want to perform authentication using a LDAP server.
In production it will be an Active Directory server, but during development I am just using [this public LDAP testing server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

I got it to work using the following classes:

A simple LDAP configuration class. 
It reads from my `application.properties` file the properties related to LDAP stuff.

```
@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {

    //Getting values from properties file
    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;
    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;
    @Value("${ldap.username}")
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;
    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword;
    @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserDnPattern;
    @Value("${ldap.enabled}")
    private String ldapEnabled;

    public LdapConfiguration() {
    }

    ... getters and setters ...

}
```

And a WebSecurityConfiguration, that actually reads from the LdapConfiguration class to use it for Authentication:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LdapConfiguration ldapConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    // Update configure method for the online test server
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapConfiguration.getLdapUrls() +ldapConfiguration.getLdapBaseDn())
                .managerDn(ldapConfiguration.getLdapSecurityPrincipal())
                .managerPassword(ldapConfiguration.getLdapPrincipalPassword())
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns(ldapConfiguration.getLdapUserDnPattern());
    }
```

With this configurations, the LDAP authentication works: I get a nice HTML page with the Login Form and using the proper credentials I can use the website.[image: login form]

And here is my issue: after the login phase, if I run something like

```
    UserDetails ud = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(ud);
```

this is what I will get:

```
LdapUserDetailsImpl@fd8cece1:
    Dn: uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com; 
    Username: tesla; 
    Password: [PROTECTED]; 
    Enabled: true; 
    AccountNonExpired: true; 
    CredentialsNonExpired: true; 
    AccountNonLocked: true; 
    Granted Authorities: ROLE_SCIENTISTS
```

I get nothing about, say, Tesla's full name (which is there in the LDAP server, as field `CN`).
It would be nice to get all data about the authenticated user.

Of course I can run a separate query to the LDAP server, asking the details about the user with username `tesla`. However, that means making an additional request to the LDAP server, so it does not seem a good solution.

Is there a way to specify which fields I want to obtain from the LDAP server when I perform authentication?
(And does it change much when working with an Active Directory server?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242165/do-we-need-to-write-customactivedirectoryldapauthenticationprovider-if-we-want-t